# How can I improve performance of soft-deletion in django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a moderately large set of models (about 350,000) backed by a MySQL InnoDB table. I'm currently using a soft delete method similar to [this one](http://terrarum.net/development/soft-deleting-with-django.html) that stores a `deleted` attribute in the database.

I have a view that shows the count of these items, and I have found that filtering the soft-deleted items is very slow.

`Item.objects.filter(deleted=False).count() -> ~400ms`

If I don't exclude the deleted objects, the count is relatively fast.

`Item.objects.all().count() -> ~140ms`

Strangely, if I add an index on the `deleted` column in the db, the time increases.

`Item.objects.filter(deleted=False).count() -> ~450ms  # indexed on 'deleted'`

What alternatives to this method of soft-deletion might I consider that doesn't make my app 3x slower?

Comment: Are you sure the final query is using your new index? What happens if you run EXPLAIN on it (you can do this via the debug toolbar)?

Comment: Adding an index to a column which has only two values has never helped much. It just increases overhead. On the other hand, virtually all databases out there optimize `COUNT` when no criteria are given. -- Have you analyzed the SQL query e.g. using Djange debug toolbar? Django is capable of doing fancy things with `count()`. If it does not optimize your query, some overhead could be generated by Django loading the objects into memory. `values()` could prevent much of this overhead.

Comment: lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/some-quick-django-optimisation-lessons/

Answer (score 0):

Store deleted items in a separate table?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: The question at the end of the post is "What alternatives to this method of soft-deletion might I consider?". My answer surely looks a lot like an actual answer to that question!

Answer (score 0):

Copied from another discussion.

"Queries become very complex" - Use views instead of tables when selecting.
"Queries become slower over time" - Use filtered indexes, instead of the regular indexes.

Comment: If you are copying other discussion, it would be nice to have the links on the answer